# LINQ query on nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of people and every person contains a list of books. How to write a LINQ query which will return the person with the highest number of books?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

// Main class
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
Person p = new Person 
{
    Name = "John";
    Books = new List<Book> {
       new Book( "Book1"),
       new Book("Book2")
    }
}
people.Add(p);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1) to order by the amount of books and then take the first person of that ordered enumerable:

```
var personWithMostBooks = people.OrderByDescending(x => x.Books.Count).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (which is faster on *large* collections: no additional memory and time for sorting) is `Aggregate`:

```
  var peopleWithMostBooks = people
    .Aggregate((s, a) => s.Books.Count > a.Books.Count ? s : a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    people.OrderBy(S => S.Books.Count).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: OrderBy returns an IEnumerable<Person>, which does not have an indexer.

Comment: Oh, oops. I'll fix that.